# Why does my iPhone 4S's screen have a yellow tint?

Tags: iphone, screen

I didnt realise the yellow tint on the phone until my friend compared his screen side-by-side. There is a yellow tint on my phone's screen. I [read around the net](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-20121897-37/iphone-4s-users-seeing-yellowish-screen-tint/) and some people state its the glue and will get better within a few days. Other sources say that its a polarization problem and will not be fixed on its own.

Can anyone shine some light on this issue ? Will it be fixed on its own over time ?

EDIT :

I compared it with 3 other phones, mine was the only one with a yellow-ish tint.

Comment: How new is the phone?

Comment: Purchased it yesterday, it came with IOS 5.0.1 .. so im assuming its the newest batch ..

Comment: There were apparently two different screens that went out with the iPhone 4s. They had two slightly different gammas. One was a warmer one (so yellowish) and the other was a cooler one (so blueish). If this is the case with the 4S, then you might just have the warmer of two screens. But if the color is *severely* yellow, then that's not normal. At this point, it's impossible to tell without a picture of your device. In any case, bring it back to an Apple Store. They'll replace it for you (the guy might say it's a "one time cosmetic replacement").

Comment: Do you have any screen protectors on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the cause of the yellowing.

I personally have seen the following situations:

1. Psycological yellow where any time you have a black border and a white area, the brain will color the white yellow. If you hide the black with a piece of white paper, the yellowness magically disappears.
2. Permanent manufacturing problem where the LCD is pinched internally, damaged, or otherwise really emitting a permanent yellow cast as measured by a [calibrated colorimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_calibration) such as the [Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/).
3. Temporary yellowness (very rare - I've just seen this a few times). I don't know why or when it went away, but several people sure agreed that one phone was off until it was restored. I don't know if it was some odd warmup temporary hardware issue, but after it was restored, it looked and tested fine with the Spyder.

Do keep in mind, not all displays are made in the same batch, same factory and that combined with the backlight settings can make a pretty large difference between models. If it's convenient to have it checked out, or you can take a picture of the colors and it's totally obvious yours has some severe color tint, then take it in and ask for a repair. If not, you'll likely need hours of time and expensive tools to even tell your phone is unique to another after using it to play games for a day or two. It will just be right and your brain will compensate for whatever calibration your phone has. A restore of the device is also a good thing to try so you don't needlessly waste time going in for service since that is the most obvious cause of the LCD passing all inspections along manufacture but you having colors that seem off to your eye at the point of receiving a new phone out of the box.

Comment: Was in the middle of writing nearly the same thing. Will upvote yours instead. The only thing I would add would be the 'glue drying' response Apple had on the 4, with the phone being so new.

Comment: Is the glue thing legit ?

Comment: I've never seen any good links to it actually causing issues. It boggles the mind that if it were an issue it wasn't fixed permanently well before the 4s ever even hit manufacturing.

Comment: @Fendi Unlikely. Never seen a credible source mention any problems with the "glue" they use to fuse the screen to the digitizer. Sounds like an internet rumor.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another reason for yellowing

The yellow appears as the glue warms up when it has not been set for long.

This happens when the phone is made and sod quickly. Basically the glue under the screen dries but it warms and turns yellow.

It will return to normall after a week or do.

Comment: Do you have a credible source to support this ?

Comment: @Fendi http://www.cultofmac.com/124444/preliminary-reports-surface-about-iphone-4s-screen-quality-issues/ and http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/iphone-4s-yellow-spot-issue-goes-away-with-a-bit-of-time/

Comment: Thanks for the sources, however they speak of yellow spots on the screen ?? The problem I have is an overall yellow tint on the whole screen :(

Comment: ?? @Fendi The first link shows a full screen affected by the yellow glue residue, not just patches.

Comment: My bad im sorry, I didnt read this "That problem was due to the iPhone 4 shipping so quickly after it was built that screens continued to show signs of a yellow adhesive used during manufacturing. Eventually the yellow residue from the adhesive disappeared leaving a normal looking display." ... so I guess it might be glue after all ??

Answer (score 0):

Your phone may be in night shift mode

To fix go to settings

Go to display and brightness

Go to night shif, turn off, if that doesn't work try going to bottom and sliding bar over to less warm and wait a few seconds